# Descending Sort of a list

Tags: sorting, haskell

Im trying to sort a list based on the average rating. I managed to make a function to return the average rating and a function to filter the database and return the films of the given year.
But how can I put all together and get the sorted output? Could you give me some hints please?

My code is:

```
-- Define Film type here
type Film = (Title, Director, Year, [Rating])

-- Define database type here
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase =
  [("Casino Royale", "Martin Campbell",  2006, [("Garry",8),("Dave", 0)])
  ,("Blade Runner",  "Ridley Scott",     1982, [("Amy",  5),("Dave", 9)])
  ,("The Fly",       "David Cronenberg", 1986, [("Fred", 7),("Dave", 4)])
  ]

-- These 2 functions are for the average rating

averageFilm :: Film -> Float
averageFilm (t, d, y, r) = averageFilmRating r

averageFilmRating :: [Rating] -> Float
averageFilmRating rating = fromIntegral ((sum [r | (_,r) <- rating])) / fromIntegral ((length rating))

---- These 2 functions are for the year filtering

displayFilmsYear :: Year -> Database -> String
displayFilmsYear year database = displayFilms (filter (filmYear year) database)

filmYear :: Year -> Film -> Bool
filmYear year (t, c, y, f)
         | year <= y = True
     | otherwise = False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

sortByRating :: [Film] -> [Film]
sortByRating = sortBy (flip $ comparing averageFilm)
```

`sortBy` allows you to sort a list using a given comparison function. This function has type

`(a -> a -> Ordering)`

where `Ordering` indicates whether the first argument is less than, greater than or equal to the first.

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

For your `Film` list your comparison function therefore has type `Film -> Film -> Ordering`. You can create such a function
with `comparing`:

```
comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> (b -> b -> Ordering)
```

In your case you need to return the ordinal value to compare films by. You already have such a function - `averageFilm`. `comparing averageFilm` therefore returns a function `(Film -> Film -> Ordering)` which compares two films by their rating.

`sortBy (comparing averageFilm)` will sort the list in ascending order by rating, so to sort in descending order you just need to flip the order of the arguments to the comparison function, i.e. `flip (comparing averageFilm)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lee. It working great. Is it possible to give me a description about what we just did if you have time?
Again thank you very much!

Comment: comparing is a function with signature "comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering" the (b -> a) function is the averageFilm, the other two b's are the films. The purpose of flip is to reverse the order that the films are applied to the comparison. This is what makes the films sort in reverse order.

Comment: @user3207652 - I've added an explanation.

Comment: The Data.Ord module also provides Down, which takes an existing ordering and reverses it. So you can also do "sortBy (comparing $ Down . averageFilm)"

Comment: Great explanations! Thank a lot guys! you answered all the questions I had in my mind! You are amazing!